# R - Calculating geographical location after a time period

Tags: r, geosphere

I have two points A and B with their respective latitude and longitude. I also have a time it takes to get from point A to point B. Let say it takes 1 hour and from A assume the driver goes straight to point B and mantains a same velocity during the trip. After 0.6 hour, I would like to know the current location of the driver (by latitude and longitude). Is there any function in the package `geosphere` or any other packages that allow me to do so? Thanks

Comment: TDo: See interpretation I used in my answer, which gets you back into the realm of a programming question. But I agree with the question being put on hold as you didn't provide any evidence of having tried this for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is better and more succinctly phrased as "how do I find the great circle route between two locations (defined as lat/long coordinates), and then find the coordinates of the point at an arbitrary percentage of the way along that route?".

First let's make an arbitrary pair of locations, called a and b:

```
df <- data.frame(locations = c("a","b"),
                 lon =runif(2,min = -180, max = 180),
                 lat = runif(2,min = -90, max = 90))
```

Now, we look at the great circle route between them. We don't need the route itself, just the distance of the whole route, and the initial direction.

```
require(geosphere)

# get the distance of a great circle route between these points
track.dist = distHaversine(p1 = df[1,c("lon","lat")],
                                   p2 = df[2,c("lon","lat")])
```

And then get the initial bearing, which we'll use in a bit:

```
track.init.bearing = bearing(p1 = df[1,c("lon","lat")],
                         p2 = df[2,c("lon","lat")])
```

The next step is to figure out where we are at arbitrary fraction of the elapsed route:

```
# figure out where we are at an arbitrary time
current.location.fraction = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1)
# get the distance
current.location.dist = current.location.fraction * track.dist

current.location = as.data.frame(destPoint(p = df[1,c("lon","lat")],
                                           b = track.init.bearing,
                                           d = current.location.dist))
```

And the last step is to check that we are the right fraction of the distance along the route:

```
check.dist = distHaversine(p1 = df[1,c("lon","lat")],
                           p2 = c(current.location$lon,
                                  current.location$lat))

print(current.location.fraction)
print(check.dist / track.dist)
```

In my tests, these last two numbers were usually within 1% of each other, suggesting this isn't too bad.

So, you can just pull the results from the `current.location` data frame.